# How change selected element in child class using main class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my code. I want to clear my histogram which is in the child class and set new parameters. But when I use in main class `FormResult formChild = new FormResult();` and the next `formChild.histogram.Series.Clear();` nothing working and I don't see any results.

In main class:

```
private void stretchHistogram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormResult formChild = new FormResult();
    formChild.histogram.Series.Clear();
    formChild.histogram.Show();        
}
```

And the child class:

```
public partial class FormResult : Form
{
    private const int MIN_VALUE = 0;
    private const int MAX_VALUE = 255;
    private int[] valueHistogram = new int[MAX_VALUE + 1];

    public FormResult()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mainForm = new APOForm();

        FormResult formResult = new FormResult();
        formResult.Owner = this;

        // Generate PictureBox
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(mainForm.getMyPath());
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pictureBox.Show();

        // Change image for bitmap array
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)pictureBox.Image;

        // Create table for pixel value for histogram

        for(int i=0; i<MAX_VALUE; ++i)
        {
            valueHistogram[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int x=0; x<bm.Width; ++x)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<bm.Height; ++y)
            {
                Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
                valueHistogram[c.R] += 1;
            }
        }

        // ------------ Generate histogram
        histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = MIN_VALUE;
        histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = MAX_VALUE;
        histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        histogram.Series.Clear();
        histogram.Series.Add("S");
        histogram.Series["S"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

        int maxAxisY = 0;

        for (int i=0; i< MAX_VALUE+1; ++i)
        {
            if(maxAxisY < valueHistogram[i]) { maxAxisY = valueHistogram[i];  }

            histogram.Series["S"].Points.AddXY(i, valueHistogram[i]);  
        }

        histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxAxisY;
        histogram.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create a new instance of the child Form (`FormResult formChild = new FormResult();`), you are then trying to change *something* on this new instance (which you never show), not in the original class object, so nothing happens. Btw, you don't set the owner *manually*: you do that when you show the new Form, as `formChild.Show(this)`. The `this` reference will be the `Owner` of `formChild`. In any case you don't set it to itself: `formResult.Owner = this;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference of the sub form in the main form, and use the reference to control the created sub form.

```
public class APOForm : Form
{
    FormResult formChild;

    // this is a pseudo method to show how to create a sub form.
    private void ShowChildForm()
    {
         formChild = new FormResult();
         formChild.MdiParent = this;
         formChild.Show();
    }

    private void stretchHistogram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(formChild != null)
        {
            formChild.histogram.Series.Clear();
            formChild.histogram.Show();
        }    
    }
}
```

And in the `FormResult` class is not necessary to new any form.

```
public partial class FormResult : Form
{
    private void FormResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var mainForm = new APOForm();

        //FormResult formResult = new FormResult();
        //formResult.Owner = this;

        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but one question, how set in ShowChildForm() MdiParent?

Comment: `formChild.Show(); formChild.MdiParent = this;`

Comment: How do you interact with `stretchHistogram` when you have `formChild.ShowDialog(this)`, a modal Form?

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I think that's not important, since I don't know how the op use the sub form, so I just wrote that method  to show the way about creation of the reference. And you're right, and since the op's comment I should make some update

Comment: The point was: *I want to clear my histogram which is in the child class and set new parameters*. Trying `formChild.histogram.Series.Clear();` being the direct consequence. When you `ShowDialog()`, any attempt from the caller Form (the Form that instantiate `formChild`) is mute, since you can't interact with the caller anymore. So, you probably want `.Show(this)`. Unless the caller is a MDIForm. Then setting the Owner is pointless.

Comment: If you close the Dialog (which is `formChild`, here), how do you update the Chart from the main class? Question title: *How change selected element in child class using main class?*. The first thing to know is if this *main class* (the caller Form) is actually an MDIForm or not. Then everything is straightforward. MDIForm? `formChild.Show();`, then do whatever you want. Standard Form? `formChild.Show(this);`, then do whatever you want using the `formChild` instance directly.